# Vitepress deploy on vercel

Tags: deployment, vercel, vitepress

when I deploy my Vitepress project on Vercel, it deploys incompletely. For example, a menu does not appear. Any ideas?

[when i deploy on vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIn3s.png)

[it's should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42PjL.png)

thanks.

i try redeploying, yarn..npm..

Answer (score 0):

Vercel-`project`-`settings`
`Build & Development Settings`-`output directory` option is set to `docs/.vitepress/dist`